# Relationships with Flask-SQLAlchemy and reflection

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm using reflection to generate two classes. One represents messages and has 2 foreign keys to a table that holds the Sending/Receiving Entity (they can be companies or people).

Given the two foreign keys, I want to create the corresponding relationships, this sounds like it should be easy, but I can't get it to work.

My code looks like this:

```
class Entity(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'Entity'
    __table_args__ = {
        'autoload': True,
        'schema': 'msg',
        'autoload_with': db.engine
    }

class FileData(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'FileData'
    __table_args__ = {
        'autoload': True,
        'schema': 'msg',
        'autoload_with': db.engine
    }
    sender   = db.relationship('Entity', foreign_keys='SenderId')
    receiver = db.relationship('Entity', foreign_keys='ReceiverId')
```

It fails with the following message:

```
InvalidRequestError: When initializing mapper Mapper|FileData|FileData, expression 
'SenderId' failed to locate a name ("name 'SenderId' is not defined"). If this is a 
class name, consider adding this relationship() to the <class '__main__.FileData'> 
class after both dependent classes have been defined.
```

I'm not sure what to make of this, since 'SenderId' is definitely one of the columns on the table, and I have no problem accessing it in other parts of the code.

Comment: Is it a one to one relationship between FileData and Entity?

Comment: Cicero, it's not. Every FileData entry will have 1 sender and 1 receiver, both from the Entity table... but each Entity table entry will be the sender or receiver of many FileData entries.

Comment: Okay, I'm trying to figure it out - but having a hard time. But one thing I can tell you is that you should be using lowercase in the foreign_keys definition. E.g: `sender.id` / `receiver.id`

Comment: Interesting, but not quite sure what you mean. From the metadata for FileData: Column('SenderId',  INTEGER(), ForeignKey(u'msg.Entity.EntityId').... So are you saying I should/can refer to the column as 'senderid'? When I just want print out some of the values, I definitely have to use 'SenderId'.

Comment: If Entity has a column named SenderId, sender_id or senderid - however it is spelled (you have to get the spelling right). When using the foreign_keys argument you should treat the row as an object and the column as a propery. Example: `entity.property` or `entity.sender_id` see [this link](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/join_conditions.html) for more info.

Comment: Entity does not have a column called SenderId, it has a column called 'EntityId'. The foreign_keys argument is used to distinguish the 2 foreign keys that both refer to the same column (SenderId and ReceiverId (foreign) pointing both to EntityId). As per your link, foreign_keys typically doesn't contain a dot and refers to a column on the table it is defined on (FileData in this case).

Answer (score 2):

It does work if the relationships are added outside of the definition. It looks like this allowed it to run the reflection first and then see the SenderId and ReceiverId columns. Like so:

```
class Entity(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'Entity'
    __table_args__ = {
        'autoload': True,
        'schema': 'msg',
        'autoload_with': db.engine
    }

class FileData(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'FileData'
    __table_args__ = {
        'autoload': True,
        'schema': 'msg',
        'autoload_with': db.engine
    }

FileData.sender   = db.relationship('Entity', foreign_keys=FileData.SenderId)
FileData.receiver = db.relationship('Entity', foreign_keys=FileData.ReceiverId)
```